# Select (trigger change) the dynamically added option of a select dropdown in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select dropdown in my webpage created dynamically as

```
<select id="mainDropDown" class="Field">
   <option data-id="-1">Select your option</option>
</select>
```

I have it dynamically populated, when another event (button click) occurs

```
$('body').on("click", "#addOption", function () {
        createOption();
        $('#mainDropDown').val($("#newOption").val()).trigger('change');
        $("#newOption").val("")
});

function createOption() 
{ 
  for (var k in OptionList) {   // OptionList has the list of options already added to the dropdown
     tempSelectedState = "";
     if ($("#newOption").val() == OptionList[k].name) {
        tempSelectedState = "selected";
     }
     $("#mainDropDown").append("<option data-id='" + OptionList[k].ID + "' " + tempSelectedState + ">" + OptionList[k].name + "</option>");
     //$('body #mainDropDown').val().trigger('change');
  }
}
```

Here the problem,  is the select change event is not getting called.

```
$('#mainDropDown').change(function () {
//.................
}
```

I am trying to call it explicitly at

```
$('#mainDropDown').val($("#newOption").val()).trigger('change');
```

But when this is called, The dynamically added option to the mainDropDown is not populated yet, and hence not accessible.

The actual functionality needed is when a new option is added, it must be selected by default, also the value change event must be triggered successfully.

Comment: Could you find any errors in console ? Is `$` loaded ? Are you waiting for `DOM` to be ready ?

Comment: I don't think you can do $("#newOption").val()

Comment: @progrAmmar, You can! https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/j7dcL1ex/

Comment: Whether you added the change handler before calling `trigger('change')`

Comment: @RayonDabre Oh I see, I thought maybe he forgot to add a hidden field called newOption

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes it has been added

Comment: _"I have it dynamically populated, when another event (button click) occurs"_  Dynamically created `option` element at `$("#mainDropDown").append("<option data-id='" + OptionList[k].ID + "' " + tempSelectedState + ">" + OptionList[k].name + "</option>");` does not appear to have `value` attribute ? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: sorry my fault, https://jsfiddle.net/Keertheee/70xgkscg/3/ is working as expected, I found that adding new option created is happening as callback such that the select is populated only after change event triggered

Comment: is the issue fixed??

Comment: yeah got fixed, the below answer was the fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addition of the new option created is a callback so, the select is populated only after change event triggered.

So remove the callback and trigger change only after populating the option.

[`This example`](https://jsfiddle.net/Keertheee/70xgkscg/3) is working as expected